# Entire sub-directory redirect via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I need to temporarily shut down a web sub-directory and all of its sub-directories without physically removing the files off the server. I want to redirect anyone and everyone to a specific webpage if they try to hit any page inside the sub-directory or its sub-directories. And I want the redirect to go to a page stored in the sub-directory because that's where its css and all its images are located.

I am trying these directives but I am not having success:

```
Options -ExecCGI -Indexes
DirectoryIndex /sub-dir/interim.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !interim.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub-dir/interim.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

Has anyone ever done something like that?

Answer (score 0):

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /sub-dir/interim.php
```

This will redirect any requests to / to /sub-dir/interim.php

Comment: Do I need any of the other directives as well -- because it didn't work all by itself.

Comment: Sorry, they don't belong to mod_rewrite, but mod_alias.

Comment: Ok. Well that directive didn't do the trick. Thanks anyway.

Comment: How did it not work? Because it is exactly for this purpose.

Comment: I tried it 2 ways thinking maybe the sub-dir needed to be defined:
RedirectMatch ^/$ /sub-dir/interim.php
RedirectMatch ^/sub-dir/$ /sub-dir/interim.php
So when I logon to http://mydomain.com/sub-dir/ I get the interim.php page (perfect!)
But when I logon to http://mydomain.com/sub-dir/index.html I get the actual webpage (I don't want that I want the interim.php page)
Then when I logon to http://mydomain.com/sub-dir/another-dir/ I get that actual webpage
So it does not achieve my objective -- sorry